# How can we delete/remove blank rows from a csv file without loading it in memory in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, csv

I have a csv file which may have empty or blank rows. I want to delete such rows but the problem is that the csv files can be potentially very large. So, I am looking for a way to do it without having to load it in memory.

The solution that works for me is using a DataTable or a StreamReader, but both of them will be using the memory which is not preferable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a StreamReader, you don't have to load the whole file into memory at once - you can do it line-by-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without loading the file.

I would use a fast CSV reader/writer from http://www.filehelpers.net - I'm sure you can link writer stream to reader stream so you write as you read and you don't need to load *the whole file* at once.